# Mailchimp custom template blank when creating a campaign

Tags: mailchimp

After editing a custom template bought online, and starting creating a campaign for testing it, I realized that the whole content disapeared.

[image: result]

Only the top css, the first table and the footer added by Mailchimp are shown.

The email works properly if exporting the HTML, and works great in the edit mode in MailChimp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the solution was cleaning up the code.

Removing all:

- mc:repeatable="..."
- mc:hideable
- mc:variant="..."
- mc:edit="..."
- data-color="..."
- data-size="..."